# Instance of v-dialog is generated twice – Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with `<v-dialog>` that appears everywhere in my Vue.js application using Vuetify.js.

Every `<v-dialog>` is loading twice on the page. You can see it by looking at how it appears:

[image: Appearance of the dialog]

If I close one dialog the other dialog stays visible and works exactly like the first. It seems like Vue is generating two instances of it.

The code of the dialog isn't the issue, I think:

```
<v-dialog
    v-model="dialog"
    persistent
    hide-overlay
    no-click-animation
>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Text</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
            <p class="subtitle-1">Some more text</p>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
                color="primary"
                depressed
            >
                Next
                <v-icon right>mdi-chevron-right</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

The `v-model` is declared in `data()`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: true,
    };
  },
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: it seems the problem is not in the code you posted. anyway, you should try setting a unique key for each dialog instance. v-dialog is a detached component, and at times vue has difficulties tracking each dialog instance.

Comment: @IgorMoraru I'd love to try that. Can you maybe show me how? Adding `key="someID"` didn't do it.